# Simple Paypal link in Excel not working

Tags: excel, paypal, hyperlink

I'm wondering why my Paypal donate link in excel is not working?

I have tried inserting an image and adding the Paypal donate button email link to the image as a hyperlink and I have tried just adding the hyperlink into an excel cell by itself with no success.

I emailed the link to my self and it works that way...

The excel file is a macro enabled workbook. excel 2010

Answer (score 0):

This is because of how Microsoft Office looks up and caches links.  I've heard of this problem but I don't know of a viable intra-Office solution.

What you can do is put your email links or buttons on a web page -- there are many free hosting providers available -- and then link to that web page from Excel.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I already have a PayPal donate button on the webpage where the excel file is downloaded... Any other ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to add a link to a cell in excel which takes a user to a page on my site which then redirects them to PayPal. A little clunky but working for now.